# Problema al contar datos

Tags: c, dev-c++

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo que contar los datos de un archivo de texto que estan separados por un salto de linea.
El problema es que al ejecutarlo, me aparece 0 datos.

Adjunto el codigo que escribi, no se donde puede llegar a estar el error.

```
#include "head.h"

int main()
{
char aux1,aux2,aux3[7];
int contador=0, j=0, n=0, i=0, t=0;
//Cargando datos
FILE *p;
p=fopen("Estadistica-Localidades-Mendoza.txt","r");
//Comprobando si existe el archivo
if (p==NULL){
    printf("El archivo no existe o no se pudo leer...\n");
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}
else{

    while (!feof(p)){
        aux1 = fgetc(p);
        if (aux2=='\n')
        {
            contador++;
        }
    }
}
printf("Cantidad de datos: %d\n",contador);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm en esta parte:

```
while (!feof(p)){
    aux1 = fgetc(p);
    if (aux2=='\n')
    {
        contador++;
    }
}
```

no debería ser if(aux1 == '\n' ) ???
En dónde estás asignando aux2?

Comment: Que idiota jaja, me volvi loco por dos horas, y no vi que solo tenia asignado aux1.

Comment: jejejeje a mi me pasa seguido.

Comment: @FernandoWithmore por ese motivo es importante reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo... si `aux2` no hubiese estado declarada en ese ámbito el propio compilador te habría avisado del error.